# Getting mysqldump: got error: 1045: access denied for user 'dev'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when deploying from capistrano task

Tags: mysql

Just for context:

I'm using Capistrano for deploying my WordPress site. specifically this one: https://github.com/markjquith/WP-Stack

You basically install this on your dev machine, set up SSH on your local and remote machines so that it can access whatever it needs to access via the Capistrano, give it the database credentials used by the staging and production sites and you're good to go.

deployment runs fine. syncing databases is where my problem is. specifically when the Capistrano runs the following code:

`mysqldump -u livesiteuser --result-file=/tmp/wpstack-26754.sql -h localhost -plivesiteuserpass livesitedbname`

which results in:

`mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'livesiteuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect`

BUT, when I run this same code myself on the remote server (where the production is at), it works.

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've made `livesiteuser` have grant access to everything. Oh yeah, using mysql `root` does the same thing.

Comment: check this user in `mysql.users`, check permissions. If all is fine may be you forgot the password? In this case you can reset it

Comment: what kind of permission am I looking for? I've given this user access to everything. and no, it's not the password. I can run the code just fine if I ssh in to the server. But, if I use Capistrano to run the code, it gives an access denied error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

if your password is `mypa$$wor&` <-- contains special characters

you need to type it as `mypa\$\$wor\&`

Special characters need to be escaped with the backslash, since the terminal interprets special characters as parameters of the command.

Comment: or use quotes around the pwd … `--password='mypa$$wor&'`

Comment: it was special characters in password

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Including the port number using *--port=3316* solved the problem.